# SAS retrieving data from monthly datasets

Tags: sas

I have 2 variables and 3 records in a sas data set, and based on the date field in that data set, I need to read different monthly data sets.
For example,
I have

```
item no.  Date
1         30Jun2015
2         31Jul2015
3         31Aug2015
```

When I read the first record, then based on the date field (`30jun2015`) here, it should merge another dataset suffixed with `30jun2015` with this current dataset.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What happens when it reads the next record? Please post some sample data and what you've tried. As this question stands it does not meet SO rules.

Comment: when it reads the second record, as the date is 31Jul2015, it has to merge with another data set for example 'Test_072015'.

Comment: You're not nearly sufficiently explaining what's going on.  "Merge with another dataset" is not at all specific - and doesn't really make sense here without a _lot_ more context.  What's going to happen when you "merge" with this other dataset?  What's the point of this?

Comment: What is the content of the other dataset? Should it have many rows, do you want all those rows inserted in the first table, duplicating the item no. and Date columns as many times?

Answer (score 0):

So as I'll hazard a guess what you're looking for I've left a bit of a gap where you'll have to specifiy the criteria for your own merge.

1) Read in base data

```
data MAIN_DATA;
infile cards;
input ITEM_NO DATE:date9.;
format DATE date9.;
cards;
1 30JUN2015
2 31JUL2015
3 31AUG2015
;
run;
```

2)  Store all dates: into macro variables date1 to daten.  Assuming ddmmyy6. is a good format for your table names

```
Data _null_;
Set Main_data;
Call symputx('date'||strip(_n_),put(DATE,ddmmyy6.));
Call symputx('daten', _n_);
Run;
```

3) Read in the variables and read the associated table - you haven't specified how to do the merge so I'll leave that up to you

```
%macro readin;
  %do i = 1 %to &daten;
    data NEW_TABLE_&&date&i..;
    set TEST_&&date&i..; /*in this step you can merge on the original table however you intend to*/
    run;
  %end;
%mend readin;
%readin;
```